# How to separately style place holder and input text data direction? One of them RTL another LTR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

My website language is an Arabic. In my login page, I have an input type=Email and its placeholder naturally is Arabic string. but all email address user typing in this input is English. 
When i add text align to this input to the left for typing english its place holder goes to the left as-well. 
Is there any way to separately set alignment to placeholder and input data ?

Comment: not by design; the placeholder should mimic the value. There is a browser-specific css handle: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/, which _might_ work for you. Edit: tested, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, with [placeholder pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder):

```css
input::placeholder {
    direction: rtl;
}
```